# Spring Rest MatrixVariable to POJO

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, spring-rest

I'm working on a Spring rest project where I want to use `@MatrixVariable`.
Unfortunately I didn't find how to automatically convert the MatrixVariable to a POJO, using Jackson the same way it's done for `@RequestBody`...

My code looks like this (with the EmployeeSkillId as a composite id):

```
    @DeleteMapping("/employee-skills/{id}")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteEmployeeSkill(@MatrixVariable(pathVar = "id") Map<String, String> id) {
        //TODO fix this so that serialization is done automatically
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // jackson's objectmapper
        final EmployeeSkillId employeeSkillId = mapper.convertValue(id, EmployeeSkillId.class);
        log.debug("REST request to get EmployeeSkill : {}", id);
        employeeSkillService.delete(employeeSkillId);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityDeletionAlert(ENTITY_NAME, id.toString())).build();
    }
```

I would prefer it to by like this:

```
    @DeleteMapping("/employee-skills/{id}")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteEmployeeSkill(@MatrixVariable(pathVar = "id") EmployeeSkillId employeeSkillId) {
        log.debug("REST request to get EmployeeSkill : {}", employeeSkillId);
        employeeSkillService.delete(employeeSkillId);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityDeletionAlert(ENTITY_NAME, id.toString())).build();
    }
```

Any Ideas on how to do that.

Thank you

Comment: do you want queryparameter instead of pathvaraible?

Comment: @sajib I'de rather not, the point is to respect REST conventions